# Use Amazon Route 53 Geolocation with a custom subnet

Tags: amazon-route53

Is it possible to use Amazon Route 53 Geolocation routing policy with a custom subnet instead of the available Continent/Country location?

I have requirements to go a bit more in depth than country level. Subnet level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible. According to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-geo Geolocation routing policy only supports a predefined list of continents, countries and states.

Comment: Was well aware of those specs, but I was hoping I've missed something, somewhere. Since they go through the trouble of mapping IP addresses to regions so you can route based on the region, it would be a no brainer to allow one to route directly based on a subnet.

Comment: Looks to me it better be done by the app serving requests, based on the remote address. Or Nginx reverse proxy, similarly to http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/nginx-redirect-backend-traffic-based-upon-client-ip-address/.

Comment: Well, the app serving requests is on the server which Route 53 should be pointing to.

Comment: Right. What I meant since Route 53 does not provide geo routing policy by the subnet - I'd implement it on the server side, serving or redirecting to a different content based on the remote address.